# Translating Linux stat(1) command into BSD stat(1) command

Tags: command-line, freebsd, bsd, coreutils, stat

**Background**

CLion's [remote project feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html) currently doesn't support FreeBSD as a remote host OS, but I want to do some hacking and see if it works. By reading the log file, I think I have spotted (one of) the issue.

```
2019-04-10 00:13:55,850 [2221079]  DEBUG -         #com.jetbrains.ssh.nio - UnixSshFS:: SshCommandRunner.execute: test -e "/tmp" 
2019-04-10 00:13:55,851 [2221080]  DEBUG - ellij.ssh.SshConnectionService - Executing SSH command: env "LC_ALL"="C" "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1" test -e "/tmp" within SSH session @3aa57c95 to <user>@<host>::22 
2019-04-10 00:13:55,963 [2221192]  DEBUG -         #com.jetbrains.ssh.nio - UnixSshFS:: SshCommandRunner.execute: stat --printf "%W%i%F%F%F%F%X%Y%s" "/" 
2019-04-10 00:13:55,963 [2221192]  DEBUG - ellij.ssh.SshConnectionService - Executing SSH command: env "LC_ALL"="C" "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1" stat --printf "%W%i%F%F%F%F%X%Y%s" "/" within SSH session @3aa57c95 to <user>@<host>:22 
2019-04-10 00:13:56,071 [2221300]   INFO -         #com.jetbrains.ssh.nio - 
Exit code 1
```

Basically, `stat(1)` behaves differently on [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) and on [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports), so the following command fails on FreeBSD-12.0, halting the entire setting up procedure:

```
$ stat --printf "%W%i%F%F%F%F%X%Y%s" "/"
stat: illegal option -- -
usage: stat [-FLnq] [-f format | -l | -r | -s | -x] [-t timefmt] [file|handle ...]
```

I thought that the `gstat` utility in `coreutils` is the GNU version of `stat`, but I turned out to be wrong; they are two different commands. I have also tried translating it myself, but I ended up with something weird:

```
$ stat -f "%B%i%T%T%T%T%a%Y%z" "/"
15006030802////15041781781024
```

**Question**

Is it possible to rewrite the command `stat --printf "%W%i%F%F%F%F%X%Y%s" "/"` for FreeBSD, so that it works the same way as its counterpart does on GNU/Linux?

Comment: Grab the source for the `stat` you want and build it on the BSD system?

Comment: @ivanivan Someone has tried to do this before, but they [failed](https://forums.FreeBSD.org/threads/compiling-gnu-stat.16868/) :(

Comment: Write a simple shell script that translates `--printf` arg to `-f` and call system `stat` with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
stat -f 0%i%HT%HT%HT%HT%a%m%z /
```

on FreeBSD should be pretty similar to

```
stat --printf %W%i%F%F%F%F%X%Y%s /
```

on Linux, with the exception that `%HT` will expand to `Directory` instead of `directory`, as `%F` does on Linux.

I just inserted a `0` instead of `%W` (birth time), since on most Linux systems that will be `0` (unknown). Replace the `0` with `%B` if you really want the birth time.

That format is quite strange though, and I don't get its purpose; I guess it could be replaced with any "unique" garbage based on file's metadata ;-)

---

> I thought that the gstat utility in coreutils is the GNU version of stat, but I turned out to be wrong; they are two different commands.

`gstat` on FreeBSD is another program (`/usr/sbin/gstat`, `gstat(8)`). You're looking for `gnustat`:

```
gnustat --printf %W%i%F%F%F%F%X%Y%s /
```

Just as with any other package `pkg info -l coreutils | grep stat` will tell you the files installed by the `coreutils` package.